# How to get records of customers who are with us for over a year in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I wanted to retrieve the total number of customers who have been with us for over 365 days and here's the query string i used which didn't work.

```
SELECT count(id) as total_customers
     , DATEDIFF(lastvisit,firstvisit) AS Duration 
  from `customers` 
having Duration >= 365
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `count()` triggers an implicit grouping and you only get one row as a result. Try without count.

Comment: I wanted just one row of result, which is the total_customers value.

Comment: But having works on this result row and can't therefore filter anything further, since it is only one row. You should rewrite that to a `where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the condition into a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT count(*) as total_customers
FROM customers
WHERE DATEDIFF(lastvisit,firstvisit) >= 365
```

But I would rather write it as:

```
SELECT count(*) as total_customers
FROM customers
WHERE lastvisit >= firstvisit + INTERVAL 365 DAY
```

Or just say "one year" instead of "365 days":

```
SELECT count(*) as total_customers
FROM customers
WHERE lastvisit >= firstvisit + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```